# how to export xml file from a s3 bucket using lambda(python) into tables in an oracle database

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm having a hard time trying to connect to my s3 bucket to read the xml file with lambda I'm using "xml.estree.ElementTree". Then I want to be able to upload them into tables in oracle.

Example: file.xml

```
<row>
 <Id >1234</Id>
 <Name>Jon</Name>
</row>
<row>
 <Id>1244</Id>
 <Name>Doe</Name>
</row>

import json
from xml.dom import minidom
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   bucketname = 'my bucket' 
   filename = 'file.xml' 
   obj = s3.Object(bucketname, filename)
   file_data = obj.get()['Body'].read()

   #parse xml
   xmldoc = minidom.parseString(file_data)
   rows = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("row")
   for row in rows:
        Id = row.getElementsByTagName("Id")[0]
        Name = row.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0]
        print("Id:% s, Name:% s" 
              (Id.firstChild.data, Name.firstChild.data))
```

This is the current code I have that reads it how can I upload it to a oracle database table.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: `xml.dom` != `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Comment: *how can I upload it to a oracle database table?* ... Did you try [researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to find an implementation and then make an attempt? One way in Python is to connect to Oracle with a DB-API like `cx_Oracle`, then run an SQL insert query on parsed XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Put xml into a datatable using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement row in doc.Descendants("row"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { (string)row.Element("Id"), (string)row.Element("Name")});
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it pointed me in the right direction, do you know how I would upload it to RDS using python? I uploaded the code that I am using

Comment: Use a DataAdapter and Command builder (on left side of line).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter?view=netframework-4.8.  The use the DataAdapter Update method to load new values in to database.  A DataAdapter has 4 commands 1) Select 2) Update 3) Insert 4) Delete.  The command builder takes the Select command and creates the other 3.  So if you do a select command of database it will fill datatable.  Then add new values to datatable and the Update the Table.  You need all 4 commands for the Adapter Update to work